# Does spark.sql("DELETE FROM ...") need terminal operation?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a simple Spark code

```
val sql = "DELETE FROM table_name"
spark.sql(sql)
```

My code reviewer said that doesn’t work without "terminal" operation like .show()

But I am pretty sure it is works

Terminal operation is needed in case of "SELECT ..." operations

But not in case of "execute" operations

Please help!

It would be great if any documents is exist

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: I was right.
That’s the nature of Spark’s lazy evaluation - it never runs SELECT queries eagerly because they are transformations.
It will only include it in a query plan until you call an action.
However, DDL/DML commands are actions, so they will be run eagerly instead.